# Why is the same database entry represented by multiple JPA bean instances?

Tags: jpa

Today I stumbled over some unexpected behaviour of EclipseLink. (I don't know if this is bound to EclipseLink or if this is the same for all JPA providers.)

I assumed that retrievals of a managed JPA bean always return references to the same object instance when issued inside the same transaction (using the same EntityManager).

If that is right, I don't know why I receive an error when I execute the following test case:

```
@Test
public void test_1() {
  EntityManager em = newEntityManager();
  em.getTransaction().begin();

  // Given:
  Product prod = newProduct();

  // When:
  em.persist(prod);
  em.flush();      
  Product actual =
    em.createQuery("SELECT x from Product x where x.id = " 
    + prod.getId(), Product.class).getSingleResult();

  // Then:
  assertThat(actual).isSameAs(prod); // <-- FAILS

  em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The statement marked with "FAILS" throws the following AssertionError:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
  <demo.Product@35dece42>
and actual:
  <demo.Product@385dfb63>
to refer to the same object
```

Interestingly the following slightly modified test succeeds:

```
@Test
public void test_2() {
  EntityManager em = newEntityManager();
  em.getTransaction().begin();

  // Given:
  Product prod = newProduct();

  // When:
  em.persist(prod);
  em.flush();      
  Product actual = em.find(Product.class, prod.getId());

  // Then:
  assertThat(actual).isSameAs(prod); // <-- SUCCEEDS

  em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Obviously there is a difference between *finding* and *querying* objects.

Is that the expected behaviour? And why?

**--Edit--**

I think I found the source of the problem: `Product` has an ID of type `ProductId`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  @Converter(name = "productIdConverter", converterClass = ProductIdConverter.class)
  @Convert("productIdConverter")
  private ProductId id;

  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
  private String name;

[...]
}
```

The [`@Convert` and `@Converter` annotations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Default_Conversions_and_Converters) are EclipseLink-specific. 
Unlike JPA 2.1 Converters you may place them on ID fields.

But it seems that in certain circumstances EclipseLink has problems to find a managed bean in its session cache if that bean uses a custom type for its ID field.

I guess I have to file a bug for that.

Comment: An EntityManager should only dish out a single object (reference) for a particular "id", as per the JPA spec. That rule applies to queries as well as find ... similarly you can make use of em.contains to see if it is "managing" a particular object. If EclipseLink is really breaking that rule then raise a bug on it. DataNucleus JPA works fine on that.

Comment: Does the "Product" have some strange equals/hashCode methods?

Comment: Good point. It was the custom ID class. Thank you for this hint. I have updated my question respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem and a solution.

We are using a custom ID class (`ProductId`) for `Product`, together with a custom (EclipseLink-specific) [Converter-Class](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Default_Conversions_and_Converters) `ProductIdConverter` which has a **bad implementation** of the `convertObjectValueToDataValue(...)` method.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  /**
   * Convert the object's representation of the value to the databases' data representation.
   */
  @Override
  public final Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object objectValue, Session session) {
    if (objectValue == null) {
      return null;
    }    
    Long longValue = ((ProductId) objectValue).getLong();
    return longValue;
  }
```

Please note that the method returns `Long` instances (or null).

But since we are using Oracle as our database backend and have declared the product's ID column as `NUMBER`, the JDBC Driver maps the column value as `BigDecimal`. This means, we have to make sure, that our `convertObjectValueToDataValue(...)` also returns `BigDecimal` instances.

So the correct implementation is:

```
  /**
   * Convert the object's representation of the value to the databases' data representation.
   */
  @Override
  public final Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object objectValue, Session session) {
    if (objectValue == null) {
      return null;
    }    
    Long longValue = ((ProductId) objectValue).getLong();
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(longValue);
  }
```

Now this method returns only `BigDecimal` instances.